# Definite article for not specific things

Tags: articles, definite-article

This is an extract from an exercise on indefinite articles from an English text-book:

> ...
>
> 2. Gary works in a restaurant. He brings **the food to the tables**. He is a waiter.

But my question is about the *definite* articles here (selected):

We don't know which food and which tables. Why the definite articles are used here then?

Comment: Which food? The food ordered by the customers. Which tables? The tables at which sit the customers who ordered the food. Etc.

Comment: Thank you. And you wrote "... by the customers" - but we don't know which customers exactly. Is "the" appropriate here?

Comment: We can use the definite article in a general sense. We don't care exactly who the customers are. They are the customers of the restaurant. A bus driver sells tickets to the people who board his or her bus.

Comment: At night we see the stars in the sky, without being able to name each one.